Где взять тестовые данные EGTS?
Хочу попробовать написать приёмную службу для данных по протоколу EGTS.
Принимать данные собираюсь с навигационных блоков ГЛОНАСС.
Реального устройства у меня пока нет.
Подскажите пожалуйста где можно взять/сформировать тестовые данные?

Тестовыми данными тут не обойдешься. Протокол подразумевает обмен данными: запрос-ответ.

Блок можно найти БУ за 5000₽

не находил ли пример взаимодействия  ретранслятор сервер-сервер?

@eri Пока даже не искал, к сожалению, до этого мне ещё далековато, пока работаю над пользовательским интерфейсом других модулей. Так как есть база данных с уже обработанными данными. Приёмная служба для EGTS это с прицелом на будущее, так как не хочется зависеть от коммерческого ПО.

может протокол ретранслятора омником есть? ;) сейчас у меня запущен приёмник с омником, но железяки серии смарт работают только через ретранслятор.

@eri сожалею, такого тоже нет.

Вот тут есть тестовые данные и тестовый клиент:
https://github.com/imhy/egts/tree/master/test

благодарю Вас, этот проект значительно больше того, что я ожидал получить.
